# How to specify multiple namespaces in DataContract attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Given a business object 'Order', how can I implement a DataContract attribute so that the Order object serializes to this:

```
<Order xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.MyCompany.SomeWebService"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...etc.
</Order>
```

There appears to be a default namespace as well as a specific one. I have been told this is a requirement to work with the web service in question.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you just need to add [`[DataContract(Name="desired name", Namespace="desired namespace")]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the class:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Order", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.MyCompany.SomeWebService")]
public class Order
{
    /// Various data members
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Having done so, you also need to mark all properties you wish to serialize with [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) since data contract serialization is opt-in.  Then the XML generated by `DataContractSerializer` will look like:

> ```
> <Order xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/appulsive.MyCompany.SomeWebService">
>     <SomeStuff>some stuff</SomeStuff>
> </Order>
> ```

As you can see, the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is automatically included.  That's because it is a [standard namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#no-xsi) that contains definitions for standard attributes including [`nil`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) (representing a null value) and [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) (holding type information for a polymorphic type).  Since these attributes are almost always required, it's conventional to add the namespace to the root element, and in fact `DataContractSerializer` does so.

Comment: Okay, so I DON'T need to specify the default namespace, only the specific one, in order for both to be included in the XML? Is that correct?

Comment: @NeilHaughton - you need to specify the namespace that `Order` is in, which becomes the default namespace.  The `i:...` namespace is a standard namespace that is auto-included.