# XML namespace missing in web api response

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have a class called `Customer`

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://noatariff.com")]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string datePart = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string timePart = now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
        this.TimeReceived = String.Format("{0}T{1}", datePart, timePart);
    }

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://noatariff.com")]
    public string TimeReceived { get; set; }    
}
```

Web api code

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ping")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomerTime()
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse<Customer>(HttpStatusCode.OK, cust, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/xml");
        return resp;
    }
```

When I access my method, I get the response as follows:

```
<Customer xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PMPI_InterconnectService.Controllers">
    <TimeReceived>2016-09-07T15:35:50.658-05:00</TimeReceived>
    <head/>
</Customer>
```

I want to get the namespace information in response.

What I am missing?

```
<mcn:Customer xmlns:mcn="http://noatariff.com">
   <mcn:TimeReceived>2016-09-07T15:46:46.845-05:00</mcn:TimeReceived>
</mcn:Customer>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327677/xml-namespaces-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Where is the 'mcn' namespace in response?  You cannot add something that doesn't exist.  It looks like you are adding your own namespace so you must process the original response and modify to meet your requirements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Serialization and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2339782/1255289)

Comment: It looks like you're actually using `DataContractSerializer`.  Have you tried simply setting the namespace in the contract via `[DataContract(Namespace = "http://noatariff.com")]` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32114023/3744182)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this :

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://noatariff.com")]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string datePart = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string timePart = now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
        this.TimeReceived = String.Format("{0}T{1}", datePart, timePart);
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string TimeReceived { get; set; }    
}
```

if you are using `DataContract` as your serilizer you don't need any thing else.